# How can I get a PHP extension name as known by composer?

Tags: php, reference, composer-php, configuration-files

I need to set up a composer.json with server requirements (e.g. php >= 5.6, lib-xml, etc). There are some examples in composer documentation, but what I need is a method to get a composer alias (ext-xxx, lib-yyy, etc) for a given PHP extension or library (e.g. php7.1-curl - Ubuntu package name).

Comment: What do you mean by "composer alias"? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Partial answer

```
composer show -p
```

Gives a list of extensions/libraries installed on the current system. So the solution is:

1. On a local linux/unix, install the library/extension in question (eg. apt install php-curl)
2. Filter the list of libraries recognized by composer to find the right result

   composer show -p | grep curl